# Find all numbers in a integer list that add up to a number

Tags: python, list, sorting

I was asked this question on an interview.  Given the following list:

```
[1,2,5,7,3,10,13]
```

Find the numbers that add up to 5.

My solution was the following:

```
#sort the list:
l.sort()
result = ()
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(i, len(l)):
         if l[i] + l[j] > 5:
             break
         elif l[i] + l[j] == 5:
             result += (l[i], l[j])
```

The idea I presented was to sort the list, then loop and see if the sum is greater than 5.  If so, then I can stop the loop.  I got the sense the interviewer was dissatisfied with this answer.  Can someone suggest a better one for my future reference?

Comment: Well, for that list, `return 5` would do it.

Comment: @MorganThrapp The idea is to make it work for any list and any result

Comment: @MorganThrapp Or 3+2

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: I think that your solutions is as good as any and simpler to comprehend.

Comment: @Quirliom You're both missing the point.  The input list doesn't matter nor does the number

Comment: Even less than your algorithm it may just be that your code shows signs of inexperience with Python. For example, iterating directly over a list is preferred to `range(len())` because the latter frequently causes off-by-one errors and is simply unnecessary in most cases. You're also using a tuple (immutable) then trying to concatenate to it, which doesn't show particularly good understanding of Python's built-in data structures.

Comment: Did they say any TWO numbers that add up to 5?  If not, your solution is a little short-sighted.

Comment: @SamHammamy Or we get it, and are making jokes.

Comment: if `l = [1,2,5,7,3,10,0]` result is `(2, 3, 0, 5, 2, 3)`

Comment: Also, you should probably first make a list only containing numbers <= 5, to reduce performance overhead.

Comment: @StevenMoseley That's good a idea

Comment: Sorting the list may have dissatisfied the interviewer since you rearranged "first-ness"

Comment: @SamHammamy Not missing the point, just showing that even this list is more complicated.

Comment: Finally, they probably wanted some acknowledgement of Big O referenced in your solution when you presented it.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I actually gave it in pseudocode and just wrote something quick for the post.  But I get your point

Comment: @StevenMoseley How would you rewrite for any two numbers?  I get the feeling it's short sighted also

Comment: @StevenMoseley since he's saying any list, that list might contain negative numbers.

Comment: @Lafexlos - good point!

Comment: @SamHammamy - For one thing, your solution is O(n^2).  You could reduce it to O(n^2 - n) simply by limiting the inner loop to the range beyond the current index of the outer loop.  There are many more optimizations you could make beyond that, but you get the point.

Comment: Just asking all those questions would be good for the interview.

Comment: We addressed negative numbers, subset size, but do we consider multiplicity in the set, e.g. 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1?

Comment: Yeah, I think the best advice you can take from this is that there were lots of questions you could / should have asked about the problem they posed to you.  What were their goals?  Performance?  Flexibility?  Code elegance?  What parameters do you have to work within?  Could you research algorithms that would help improve performance?  What's the size limitation on the set?  Value bounds?  Etc.

Comment: Note that if you're only looking for *pairs* that sum to 5, you can do this in O(N) time, and that's the solution I'd expect to see if we're only handling the x+y=5 case.

Comment: @SamHammamy - FYI, I added an answer below that should demonstrate performance considerations you could have made.

Answer (score 4):

This will return all elements of the powerset of the input that sum up to 5:

```
>>> input = [1,2,5,7,3,10,13]
>>> import itertools
>>> def powerset(l):
...     return itertools.chain.from_iterable((itertools.combinations(l, i) for i in range(len(l)+1)))
...
>>> filter(lambda v: sum(v) == 5, powerset(input))
[(5,), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: this answer is pretty sweet

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this visits *every* subset of the list, so it's O(N2^N)

Comment: @Quirliom Yeah but if you're interviewing for a Python job, and they ask you this, and you go, "No problem!" and smack this down on the table, I'm pretty sure you're hired anyway.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Sure, but it's nice to note some of the internals as well :)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It was actually a DevOps job :)

Comment: This is inefficient if `len(input) == 1000` for example takes too long

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
from itertools import permutations
from random import randint


base_list = [randint(-10, 10) for x in range(20)]

def five_sum(base_list, combinations):
    has_negatives = any([base for base in base_list if base < 0])
    if not has_negatives:
        filtered_list = [base for base in base_list if base <= 5]
    else:
        filtered_list = base_list
    perms = list(permutations(filtered_list, combinations))
    filtered_perms = [perm for perm in perms if sum(perm) == 5]
    print(filtered_perms)
    for perm in set(filtered_perms):
        yield perm

print(base_list)
print(list(five_sum(base_list, 2)))
```

In an ideal world where I had unlimited Memory, I would replace the `combinations` parameter with `perms = [list(permutations(filtered_list, i)) for i in range(len(filtered_list) + 1)]`

Comment: Fails for negative lists containing negative numbers.  Fails for lists containing duplicate numbers.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Good point. I just added a check for negatives, it should handle them fine now.

Answer (score 2):

another solution using dictionaries

```
from collections import Counter

l = [1,2,2,5,7,3,10,0,-5]
counter = Counter(l)
keys = counter.keys()
result = []
key = keys.pop()

while True:
  if 5-key in counter:
    result.append((key, 5-key))
    counter[key]-=1
    if counter[key]<=0:
      del counter[key]
      if len(keys) == 0:
        break
      key = keys.pop()
    counter[5-key]-=1
    if counter[5-key]<=0:
      del counter[5-key]
  else:
    del counter[key]        
    if len(keys) == 0:
      break
    key = keys.pop()

print(result)
```

you get

```
[(-5, 10), (5, 0), (3, 2)]
```

---

> with `len(l)==1000` timeit for proposal solutions:

```
from timeit import Timer

t = Timer(jose)
print t.timeit(number=1)
#0.00108003616333
t = Timer(dan)
print t.timeit(number=1)
#hangout
t = Timer(morgan)
print t.timeit(number=1)
#0.000875949859619 <--- best time
t = Timer(steven)
print t.timeit(number=1)
#0.0118129253387
t = Timer(sam) #OP
print t.timeit(number=1)
#0.0160880088806
```

Comment: Woah, I have best time? I actually thought mine would be the least efficient.